# Is any way to use twig in php?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

All of my files are in PHP and now I have problem, because I have to use twig code on my PHP page:

```
{% block fos_user_content %}
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

Is there any way to include .twig file in .php file? Or does somebody know how to convert this twig code to PHP? Or maybe somebody know some tutorial for `FOSUserBundle` which is written in PHP?

Comment: Have you read a line of the doc ? http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html

Comment: You can have your `htacces or in php.ini` so that .twig files are parsed as .php. Besides that, you can include any file you want in your code, dosen't* matter what file type.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you trying to do, but i'll try to help you :

- you can't include twig in php(2 engine for templating, why?)
- you can "use php code" in your twig template with [twig extension](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)(but please read doc as @Yenne Info said)
- You can render twig template with controller method renderView($template, $params)

But do you really use symfony2?